# I want a scroller in my Activity containing a Fragment with a GridView inside

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, scroller

I want a scroller in my activity which contains a Fragment and that fragment has a GridView which is using a CustomAdapter , now grid itself provides a scroller but I want the main activity which is calling that grid from a fragment to have a scroller, but every time I try to give a scroller to that activity, the grid's height gets diminshed.

I tried giving the scroller to the fragment file too but it doesn't work and all the views get stuck to a single place.

Here is my code. MainActivity.xml :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tread_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/tread_details_fragment"
                class="com.example.sample_cr411.Trailer_Fragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </fragment>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And i am calling that fragment in MainActivity.java:-

```
Vehicle_Fragment fragment1 = new Vehicle_Fragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.relative_tread_fragment, fragment1).commit();
```

And the Fragment vehicle_details.xml file:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#000000"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="6"
        android:rowCount="2">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Fragment Vehicle_Fragment.java program file :-

```
public class Vehicle_Fragment extends Fragment {

private GridView gridView;
private EditText axel_count;
String axel_count_no;
static final String[] Axel = new String[] { "axel1", axel2","axel3","axel4","axel5","axel6"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_details, container,false);

axel_count = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_axels);
axel_count_no = axel_count.getText().toString();

gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid1);
gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), Axel));

return view;
}
```

Now finally the griditems.xml which gets inflated in my CustomAdapter:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/...
<EditText
android:id="@+id/...

<TextView
android:id="@+id/...

<Button
android:id="@+id/...
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Custom Adapter.java is:-

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] gridaxelrows) {
    this.context = context;
    this.gridaxelrows = gridaxelrows;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gridaxelrows.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View gridView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditems, null);
        tread_size = (EditText) gridView.findViewById(R.id.tread_size);
        tirebutton = (Button) gridView.findViewById(R.id.check_button);
    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }
    return gridView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nested scrollable Views are to be **avoided**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein But that grid is at the bottom of the page and grid itself is scrollable but on changing the orientation to lanscape the whole page is not visible .. thats y i want a scroller on the page so that whole page is scrollable .. i don't think this condition comes under nested scrollable View !!